# Issue with importing metadata. dspace

Tags: dspace

I'm trying import metadatas but the dspace import just a part.

The CSV file contains 7275 lines but 439 lines are not imported.

And when i try import the 439 lines in a separate file the system returns this message:

"There were no changes detected". But the file data of 439 lines is different.

How to solve this?

Comment: Here are a few things to try: Verify a couple of the id fields.  Look for unexpected white space or newline characters.  Make sure the column counts match the header row.

Comment: Can you send a sample of imported lines and those that could not be imported?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. It turned out the problem was with multiple new lines in the dc.description column (paragraphs were terminated by two new lines). The text was exported from DSpace and untouched so there seems to be an issue when DSpace parses imported data, whether modified or not.

Removing the multiple new lines solved the problem and the importer picked up my changes.